# Create event and send calendar invitation emails, triggered from spreadsheet via apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

My script creates a calendar event every time someone sets the value in column 14 to "confirmed".
Event is created correctly, and guests are added to it.

However, it's important that the script also sends out invitation emails. This part I can't get to work. Any ideas?

Here's my script (with Google Calendar API activated):

```
 function onConfirmedEdit(e) {
 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  
  if (e.range.columnStart === 14 && e.value === "Confirmed") {
    const showDate = sheet.getRange(row, 6).getValue();
    
    if (showDate instanceof Date) {
      const startTime = new Date(showDate);
      startTime.setHours(19, 0, 0, 0); // Set the time to 19:00
      const endTime = new Date(showDate);
      endTime.setHours(23, 30, 0, 0); // Set the time to 23:30

      const calendarId = 'xyz@example.com'; // Replace with your calendar ID
      const calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
      const eventTitle = sheet.getRange(row, 7).getValue();
      const location = sheet.getRange(row, 10).getValue();
      const eventDescription = `This is a test event`;
      const guestlist = ['xyz2@example.com', 'xyz3@example.com', 'xyz4@example.com'];

      const eventOptions = {
        description: eventDescription,
        guests: guestlist.join(),
        sendInvites: true,
        sendUpdates: "all",
      };

      const newEvent = calendar.createEvent(eventTitle, startTime, endTime, eventOptions);

    } else {
      Logger.log('Invalid show date format: ' + showDate);
      // Handle the case where the show date format is not as expected
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: About `However, it's important that the script also sends out invitation emails. This part I can't get to work.`, when I saw your script, when your script of `const newEvent = calendar.createEvent(eventTitle, startTime, endTime, eventOptions);` is correctly run with valid values, the users can receive the email. So, in this case, it is required to know the method for correctly replicating your current issue. So, can you provide detailed information about your current issue?

Comment: I figured out in the meantime that the invitation emails get sent, if the owner of the calendar is a usual google account. However, it doesn't seem to work if the calendar belongs to an account with a non-workspace-domain. I was trying to invite people to the calendar event of xyz@example.com's calender, while this account is neither a workspace, nor a regular google account. Seems right, or should it be possible even with this account's calendar?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `However, it doesn't seem to work if the calendar belongs to an account with a non-workspace-domain`, in this case, how about confirming your situation to the administrator of your Google Workspace? Because when the email outside of Google Workspace can be sent, the user can receive the email. So, I'm worried that the reason for your current issue might depend on the setting of Google Workspace. If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. The google calendar i'm creating the event in, belongs to an account that is not a workspace account. It's an account set up with an external email address, has no Gmail, but still has a calendar. Running the script like shown in my initial question will not send any emails, but when I run it with "calendarID" set to eg. my personal Gmail account's calendar, Emails are sent out successfully.

Comment: First, the whole issue of the `google calendar i'm creating the event in, belongs to an account that is not a workspace account.` That needs to be up in the second paragraph of the question because it is the **why** of `I can't get [this] to work`. Second, you've already got invitee email addresses (in the spreadsheet and/or the script), so the mechanics of sending an email should be straightforward (famous last words :), In which case, the remaining unanswered issue would seem to be **what is the email system/platform/account from which you do want to send the invitations**?